# Does Windows active directory sync data from user's profile?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-server-2003, active-directory

Does Windows active directory sync data from user's profile? I mean Desktop, Downloads, outlook or whatever in the profile.
I want my windows client's outlook data to automatically sync to my windows server. Is active directory good for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory itself doesn't, the AD Database only synchronises users account data (usernames, password hashes, forename, surname etc)...  I think what you are after is called a roaming profile.

If you have a share on a server where you want to store all of this data, you can create a folder for each user to hold their data.  You can then set a folder in the users profile which will store the users data anbd synchronise at logon/logoff:

[image]

You set this by creating the folder and giving the user full control over it, then you go to Active Directory Users and Computers > Your User > Profile Tab.

For bonus points, you can also set their "Home Folder" to the same path - and this will make "X:" (or whatever drive letter you choose) go directly to the server copy of the profile... or more specifically, their "My Docyments" folder.

For additional bonus points - redirect the users "My Documents" folder to the server copy only to keep profiles small and also stop any issues with data sync.  This can be done with group plicy (installed by default with active directory) by following this guide:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783674%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I've been a windows server and active directory administrator for nearly 10 years - its a case of trial and error (in a test domain, not your live one!) and it will become very clear very quickly.

Comment: I am very new to all this and need a lot of guidance.

Comment: hi, i accomplished what i was looking for, but outlook doesn't sync. can i change this? can i make it sync outlook?

Comment: Ask a new question and people may be able to weigh in and let you know.. no time to explain today

Comment: just accomplished the same. However, thank you for the kind suggestion. :)